# Divide number to group and the total of group, that always is greater than 0

Tags: algorithm

Situation: I have a list of number 1, 2, 3, -4, -5, 7, 1, 8, -2, -7,... . The total numbers in this list, that always is greater than 0.

Problem: We need to divide this list into groups.
The requirement of the group:

- Maximum number of elements in a group is 7.
- Total numbers in a group, that always is greater than 0.

Do you have any idea about this problem? Could you please help me to provide algorithms to solve this case?
Thank you very much!

Comment: What do you mean by ''Max number is contained a group is 7."?

Comment: Thanks for watching my question. I mean for each group only contains a maximum of 7 numbers.

Comment: That means the initial list will have at most 14 elements.

Comment: I am not even getting your question now... You only want to divide the list into two such that both have at least 1 element and at most 7. Am I correct?

Comment: The initial list will have no limit elements. We need to count 7 numbers for 1 group and 7 numbers next to another group, the loop will continue until the end of the initial list and meet the conditions above.

Comment: Is (2,8,-2,-7),(1, 3, -4, -5, 7, 1) possible solution? Can we reorder items? Give some examples. Unlimited list looks strange...

Comment: As your question from MBo. It is almost what I need.The group 1 is  (1, 3, -4, -5, 7, 1, 2), the group 2 is (8,-2,-7) not meet the requirement, because group 2 has total < 0. If the initial list has more element than 1, 3, -4, -5, 7, 1, 2,8,-2,-7, 1, 2, 3, -2, 5 - We will divide to The group 1 is  (1, 3, -4, -5, 7, 1, 2), the group 2 is (8,-2,-7, 1, 2, 3, 2), and the group 3 is (5)

Comment: So you need to solve subset sum problem with count limit for some list pieces. Subset sum should be positive but as small as possible (to provide possibility to make another subsets)

Comment: The unlimited initial list, I get from another system, If the system provides how many elements I have to get then.

Comment: Could you please speak clearly your solution, MBo? I don't much understand.

Comment: @NguyenAnhDuy Basically you want to divide the list into subsets such that both have the sum of elements greater than 0 and the frequency of elements is limited to 7.

Comment: Nguyen Anh Duy Look for `subset sum problem` - in your case problem is more complex due to: limited subset size; inexact sum value (>0); unrestricted list; perhaps another issues while problem is not defined completely.

Comment: Hi @YashShah! That what I need.

Comment: Hi @MBo! Thanks for your reply! I will try to research it.

Comment: @Nguyen Anh Duy, can u kindly provide a reference or link to the original problem?

Comment: Hi @DeepakTatyajiAhire! I just re-posted my question and explain it more clearly. Could you please review my question?

Comment: In general, not always solvable { -12, 1,1,1, 1,1,1, 1,1,1, 1,1,1, 1} can not meet split requirements..

Answer (score 0):

I would like to re-post my question to explain more clearly.

I have a list of transaction history with the corresponding amount.

```
List<Invoice> items = new List<Invoice>() {
                    new Invoice("808861", -45.85),
                    new Invoice("822634", -144.32),
                    new Invoice("822635", -56.63),
                    new Invoice("835308", 2970.55),
                    new Invoice("835309", 869.36),
                    new Invoice("835310", 3050.73),
                    new Invoice("835311", 657.74),
                    new Invoice("835312", 168.42),
                    new Invoice("835348", 2922.69),
                    new Invoice("835349", 324.5),
                    new Invoice("835350", 906.3),
                    new Invoice("835351", 420.21),
                    new Invoice("835352", 851.7),
                    new Invoice("838880", 158.43),
                    new Invoice("838881", 2062.46),
                    new Invoice("838882", 567.26),
                    new Invoice("838883", 40.96),
                    new Invoice("838884", 207.16),
                    new Invoice("838889", 2726.13),
                    new Invoice("838890", 29.25),
                    new Invoice("838891", 1458.28),
                    new Invoice("838892", 219.58),
                    new Invoice("839930", 2791.99),
                    new Invoice("839931", 455.47),
                    new Invoice("839932", 514.94),
                    new Invoice("839934", 666.78),
                    new Invoice("840758", -341.34),
                    new Invoice("855741", -113.55),
                    new Invoice("855973", -85.46),
                    new Invoice("866848", -39.53),
                    new Invoice("877471", -58.17),
                    new Invoice("877472", -58.17),
                    new Invoice("878790", -459.53),
                    new Invoice("892869", -6353.36)
        };
```

I want to divide the transaction history into many small groups with the following conditions:

```
1. Maximum for each group will contain 26 transaction history.
2. The total amount in each group must be greater than 0.
3. The last group contains the remaining histories as long as the condition is greater than 0.
```

Below I write indiscriminately to calculate the trial total of the transaction, but the final group is still less than 0.

```
private static void ShowSumOf26Invoice(List<Invoice> list, int from, int to)
        {
            if (list.Count > 26)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Total amount from: " + from + " to " + to + " : " + items.GetRange(0,26).Sum(x => x.Amount));
                items.RemoveRange(from - 1, 26);
                from = from - 1 + 26;
                to = to + 26;
                ShowSumOf26Invoice(items, from, to);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Total amount from: " + from + " to " + (to - 26 + items.Count) + " : " + items.Sum(x => x.Amount));
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Total amount: " + items.Sum(x=>x.Amount));
            int from = 1;
            int to = 26;
            ShowSumOf26Invoice(items, from, to);

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to end the program!");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```